# Getting hash tree of trees belonging to an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Even though I think this is a fairly common problem, I've not been able to find a single resource answering this question.

I have a `Comment` model that can be associated with a `Resource` or have a parent, which is another comment. Thus allowing nested comments. A root comment is always associated with a `Resource`.

What I am trying to achieve now is to get the hash tree of the comments that are associated with a `Resource` so that I can effectively get the root comments, and all the comments that is nested within a rooted comment.

I am fairly new to tree structures, but I believe how I'm doing it now is not the effective (performance wise), nor the correct way to use a tree structure.

resources_controller.rb

```
def show
 @comments = @resource.comments.includes(:children)
end
```

resources/show.html.erb

```
<%= comments_tree_for @comments %>
```

comments_helper.rb

```
def comments_tree_for(comments)
  comments.map do |comment|
    render(comment) +
      (comment.children.size > 0 ? content_tag(:div, comments_tree_for(comment.children), class: 'replies') : nil)
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

However if I run `Comment.hash_tree` in my console, it returns the trees. Now what I'd like to accomplish is a way to actually utilize `hash_tree` on my current structure.

Relevant article: https://www.sitepoint.com/nested-comments-rails/